# Deleted Repetitive Text Across Multiple Files

Tags: powershell, repeat

Within a folder containing multiple individual music files the name of the album and band name appear before the song # and title (e.g. Band_Name_Album_Name_01_Song_Title.mp3). Each track in the folder is titled this way. Is there a powershell command I can use to delete the repetitive band name and album name so that only the track number and song name remain?

**I want to change the following folder:**

Band_Name_Album_Name_01_Song_Title1.mp3

Band_Name_Album_Name_02_Song_Title2.mp3

Band_Name_Album_Name_03_Song_Title3.mp3

Band_Name_Album_Name_04_Song_Title4.mp3

Band_Name_Album_Name_05_Song_Title5.mp3

Band_Name_Album_Name_06_Song_Title6.mp3

**To this:**

01_Song_Title1.mp3

02_Song_Title2.mp3

03_Song_Title3.mp3

04_Song_Title4.mp3

05_Song_Title5.mp3

06_Song_Title6.mp3

Note: I would do this manually if there were only one folder but there are multiple folders like this.

Comment: You could also use [RegexRenamer](http://regexrenamer.sourceforge.net/) to do that.

Comment: What is your code? Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service”

Answer (score 0):

The following *should* work provided the filenames are consistent.

Remove the "-recurse" switch if it doesn't need to go through subfolders.

```
get-childitem -path "C:\Folder\Folder" -include *.mp3 -file -recurse | foreach {
    try
    {
        $newFileName = $_.name.split('_')[4..6] -join ('_')
        rename-item -path "$($_.Directory)\$($_.name)" -newName "$($_.Directory)\$($newFileName)"
    } 
    catch
    {
        write-error "Unable to rename ($_.FullName)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To rename all `*.mp3` files in the current folder (`.`):

```
Get-ChildItem . -Filter *.mp3 |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.*_(\d{2}_.*)', '$1' }
```

Add `-Recurse` to process all files recursively, i.e. in the target folder's subtree.

`-replace '.*_(\d{2}_.*)', '$1'` transforms each input filename to just the part starting with the song index (i.e., drops the band-name and album-name part); this regex-based approach is flexible in that can deal with a variable number of tokens both before and after the song index.

Note that any files whose names does not match the regex are left untouched.